# Kafka Handover Closed Exception in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I deployed Flink on Kubernetes cluster after deployment in some time it is started through below error and because of flink restart strategy the flink is not processing any data after giving 5 retries to recover the job. Below is error i am seeing in flink task manager logs

```
2021-02-09 14:05:05.545 [Source: Custom Source -> Filter -> Map (10/12)] WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask  - Error while canceling task.
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Handover$ClosedException: null
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Handover.close(Handover.java:182)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.cancel(KafkaFetcher.java:175)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.cancel(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:818)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.cancel(StreamSource.java:147)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.cancelTask(SourceStreamTask.java:136)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.cancel(StreamTask.java:602)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task$TaskCanceler.run(Task.java:1355)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-02-09 14:05:05.545 [Sink: Unnamed (6/12)] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task  - Sink: Unnamed (6/12) (d9c63e510c0a10e749e634e04db2f06f) switched from CANCELING to CANCELED.
2021-02-09 14:05:05.546 [Sink: Unnamed (6/12)] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task  - Freeing task resources for Sink: Unnamed (6/12) (d9c63e510c0a10e749e634e04db2f06f).
2021-02-09 14:05:05.545 [Source: Custom Source -> Filter -> Map (4/12)] WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask  - Error while canceling task.
org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Handover$ClosedException: null
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Handover.close(Handover.java:182)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.cancel(KafkaFetcher.java:175)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.cancel(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:818)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.cancel(StreamSource.java:147)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.cancelTask(SourceStreamTask.java:136)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.cancel(StreamTask.java:602)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task$TaskCanceler.run(Task.java:1355)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-02-09 14:05:05.546 [Sink: Unnamed (6/12)] INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task  - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for task Sink: Unnamed (6/12) (d9c63e510c0a10e749e634e04db2f06f) [CANCELED]
```

I searched in the internet but didn't get any info on above error but i got this [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/zhangyupeng0528/article/details/111308323) saying that the number of partitions should be equal to parallelism in flink. So i have 6 partitions in my topic so i added flink parallelism 6 still getting the above error. It is coming in two scenarios either at boot strap time of the flink application or after processing heavy volume of payloads. I increased network buffers also thought of may be flink is not getting enough network buffers while processing data still no luck. I am using Flink 1.10.0 and flink-connector-kafka_2.12. Please help me in resolving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error happens during cancellation - there should be another exception before that (on a different taskmanager?).

Comment: @Arvid Heise thanks for you reply, but i am seeing only this error in task manager logs

Comment: Then this means that the actual error is swallowed. Do you have the luxury to update your Flink to a later version? (Latest bugfix of 1.10 or even more recent version)